# MiKTeX 2.9 update packages and shortcut of MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, miktex-update

I have done a full update of the packages of MiKTeX 2.9, it worked fine, no error message and the too old package that was blocking the compilation do not block anymore my compilation

Fine, BUT all the shorcuts for MiKTeX do not work anymore, I cannot  use the package manager, the update or settings any more.

I'm on windows 10, in the start menu, there are shorcut for the package manager, the settings, and updates of MiKTeX 2.9. These shortcut do not work any more. The executables are not there any more

[image: short cuts windows 10]

Do you know why and what would be the solution to recover an access to these tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that you got a new command center for MiKTeX with the new version: **MiKTeX Console**. It includes all configuring tools together in one tool:

[image: new command center]

The old package manager you can get with clicking on `Packages` (see red arrow, marked 3), the old update manager you can get with `Updates` (red arrow, 2) or just click on `check for updates` at the end of the shown window and the old settings manager you can get with `Settings`(red arrow, 1) ...

With the new version of MiKTeX all old programs are deleted, only MiKTeX Console is working now. Therefore your old shortcuts can not work any longer and please note that they are not deleted by the installing routine for the new MiKTeX version. Simply delete them and use now MiKTeX Console ...

If you can not see the MiKTeX Console, please click on the windows sign on the left in the taskbar, choose apps and search for MiKTeX Console. Right Click on it to add it to the start menu etc.

Comment: Do you know the name of te executable ? I do not find the console

Comment: See `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-console_admin.exe` or  `miktex-console.exe` if you have a user installation in another path ...

Comment: thank you, I found it.  I added the shortcut for the executable. No registration as application in windows though. The unique console tool is much better. The old versions were like a labyrinth